# Pip install Mysql para Pynthon en windows 10 de 64 bits me da error SKD 7.1

Tags: mysql, python, pip

En una Notebook con Windows 10 de 64 Bits, con Python 3.3 instalado.
Al querer instalar Mysql por intermedio de Pip en Python me produce el siguiente error:

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Windows SDK 7.1": www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=8279

Instale el Microsoft Windows SKD 7.1 de acuerdo a la ruta seleccionada y me sigue produciendo el mismo error.

Tengo alguna otra manera para bajar los modulos de Mysql ???

Comment: Mirate los pasos que detallan en las respuestas de [esta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26473854/python-pip-has-issues-with-path-for-ms-visual-studio-2010-express-for-64-bit-ins) pregunta de [so]. Si pudieras usar la versión 3.4 o 3.5 de python en vez de la 3.3 podrias conseguir los binarios directamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes instalar una versión ya compilada (wheels).
http://pythonwheels.com/

Existe un repositorio no oficial muy útil para estos casos: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Sólo tendrías que bajar la correspondiente a tu sistema, `*‑cp33‑cp33m‑win_amd64.whl` en tu caso, e instalarla con pip:

```
pip install [ruta]\[fichero].whl
```

Dependiendo de la configuración del sistema es posible que necesites hacerlo como administrador.