# Error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat).

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-workbench

He estado tratandode conectar Python con MySQL y no he podido conectarme, estoy usando el Python 3.4 y MySQL Workbench.

Ya tengo isntalado el Microsoft Visual C++ 2010.

Si alguien sabe, por favor ayudenme.

Comment: Es un error típico al intentar instalar librerías con código C que ha de ser compilado en Windows... Supongo que estarás intentando instalar mediante pip. ¿cuando se produce el error?¿Con qué comando?¿Estas intentando instalar Mysqlclient?¿Usas Python 3.4 de 64 o de 32 bits?

Comment: Python 3.4 64 bits. Si estoy intentando instalar mediante pip. Cuando ejecuto el comando de pip install mysql-connector o cualquiera relacionado a mysql me arroja el mensaje " Error: Microsoft Visual C++ 10.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat). " y tengo instalado el visual c++ 10.0

Comment: Hace falta colocar algo en el path?

Comment: Puedes seguir los pasos de https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_10.0_standalone:_Windows_SDK_7.1_.28x86.2C_x64.2C_ia64.29 o instalar Visual C++ Express 2010. La otra opción es instalar un binario precompilado, esta es una pregunta relacionada:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/37476/15089

Comment: Si no quieres complicarte usa los binarios precompilados que proporciona Christoph Gohlke de la Universidad de California: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/. en tu caso para `mysqlclient` debes descargarte https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/zhckc95n/mysqlclient-1.3.12-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl,. Luego abres una terminal (CMD) en el directorio de descarga y haces `py -3.4 -m pip install mysqlclient-1.3.12-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl`. Cuando todos los paquetes se pasen al estánder wheels nos evitaremos estos problemas con Windows.